# Using the UP1 Mobile Controls how can you create a link to an external web site?

Tags: xpages, mobile-controls

Using the Outline control in a mobile page and setting it's href to a URL doesn't seem to work for me. Moving to another mobile page does in fact work. The older OpenNTF controls used to support this and I am wondering if I am missing something as you would think that this functionality would be supported.

Comment: if you provide screenshots or xsp code it is easier to help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basicLeafNode is used to create a node that contains an external url.

If your pointing to a different server you need to use the full http:// format.

If your pointing to a different nsf on the current server you can use the /.ibmxspres/domino/filename.nsf format

Comment: Declan - I will give this a try. I however thought that the touching the whole row would link to say an external site such as http://openntf.org. I am working on an app that will have lists of websites for a demo. Be back at you with an answer.